# Does connectionless mean the same as multiplexing?

Tags: terminology

The concepts of connection-oriented and connectionless  and the concept of multiplexing come to me in different chapters in Tanebaum's Computer Networks.

But after some thoughts, I feel that connection-oriented means reserving a path for a communication exclusively, and connectionless means allowing multiple communications do multiplexing in the form of time-division (specifically, divide a message into datagrams, and allow datagrams of different messages to travel a shared link in different times). So am I right that connectionless and multiplexing mean the same, and connection-oriented and non-multiplexing mean the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. These are two completely different, unrelated concepts. Multiplexing means that you are transferring multiple signals, and there are different ways of multiplexing.  For instance many telephone systems use Time Division Multiplexing (TDM) but the telephone calls carried are connection-oriented.

Comment: Thanks. If a communication is connection-oriented, isn't a path  reserved for only one communication? How can multiple communications share a path, i.e. multiplex?

Comment: That happens all the time. On a TDM line like a T1 for voice, each simultaneous call gets a limited time period. The call certainly lasts longer than the small time period, but it only gets to use the very small time period while sharing the line with other calls.

Comment: With TDM, what does connection-oriented mean then? Doesn't a connection reserve a path for a communication from the communication's beginning till its end?

Comment: Yes, but for most, or all of that path, the path can be shared, divided by time, for multiple calls.  A standard phone call only needs 64Kbps, but a T1 line can multiplex a couple of dozen on that T1 line.

Comment: My confusion still exists. In TDM, do you break/pause a connection of a communication, to let other communication use the part of the path taken up by the connection, and then later resume the connection? I think, in connection-oriented service, a connection for a communication lasts from the beginning of the communication till its end, so it can't be paused to free the part of the path it takes up, and then be resumed.  I looked up the concepts of connectionless and connection-oriented, but might not get their definitions correctly. Similar with multiplexing. Can you share your definitions?

Comment: The Time Division in TDM means each call gets a very small slice of time to send something, and these time slices are interleaved between calls. The T1 example only gives the call certain time periods in which to send data, even if it is the only call on the line. A T1 operates at 1.544 Mbps, but each call only needs 64 Kbps, so multiple calls can operate at the same time The bottom line is that multiplexing and connection/less-oriented protocols have nothing to do with each other. You are confusing a couple of things. Google T! multiplexing for details.

Comment: Thanks. what resource does a connection reserve for a communication then? Does a connection merely mean that a path is fixed after it is chosen for the communication? I read in Tanenbaum's book that  a connection-oriented service is inefficient because it won't let other communication to use the same path even if the current communication is paused.

Comment: Or do I misunderstand it?

Comment: For a T1 line at 1.544 Mbps, there are 1.536 Mbps of bandwidth, after subtracting overhead. Each channel (time slot) gets 1/24th of the time, giving each channel 64 Kbps. A channel on the multiplexed line is what gets reserved. Each traffic stream thinks it has sole use of a 64 Kb link because it can transmit unimpeded at 64 Kb, but it is a single multiplexed link. This is just one common example of multiplexing, but there are other ways to multiplex.

Answer (score 2):

it sound like , connection-oriented or connection less are the ***conditions*** need to be meted before any signal transfer but multiplexing (TDM , FDM , CDM ...etc) are the ***way of transfer*** the signal after the link establishment.
***connection-oriented*** means that the connection need to be granted from end to end before any data or signal transfer  (TCP is connection orignted , source will never send the next session until the first one is granted to be delivered )
***connectionless*** means no dedicated path or BW or end to end grantee is needed (UDP is connectionless protocol where all the session will be delivered regardless what session is doped)
[image]
***multiplexing*** is the way of send multiple signal on certain time interval or frequency range based on the type of this multiplexing
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By Tanebaum's definition, the internet is "connectionless". No dedicated, reserved path is created between any two nodes. A stream of packets are free (and often *do*) follow independent paths, per packet, and may be asymmetric -- flowing a different path in each direction.